# extension class loaders

Tags: java, classloader

How would i use extension class loaders to load some class found in an non-extension directory?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Wrong on every level - don't do it.  I seriously doubt that you need to write a custom class loader.  The good reasons to do so are rare as hen's teeth.

Answer (score 0):

We have Application Class Loader, also known as System Class Loader, for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [URLClassloader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).  URLClassloader lets you pass in urls and then will load classes from those urls.